# Using DateTime properties in Code-First Entity Framework and SQL Server

Tags: datetime, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have an example class `book`:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

When I attempt to add a new `book` to the `BookDb` context...

```
using (BookDb db = new BookDb())
{
    Book book = new Book {
        Name = "Some name",
        DateAdded = DateTime.Now
    };

    db.Books.Add(book);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

... an error is thrown:

> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**: The conversion of a datetime2 data
>   type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The
>   statement has been terminated.

---

I've found that the cause of this is the incompatible `datetime` types between .NET and SQL Server. There is a way to tell EF to use SQL Server's format in traditional Entity Framework, but **how do I do it in *Code-First* Entity Framework?**

I am using EF4 on .NET 4 (MVC 3 web app) and SQL Server 2008 Express.

Comment: Did you set the clock of your computer to something like year 1750 or earlier?

Comment: I wasn't serious :) See my answer.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can specify the type in Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
    .Property(f => f.DateTimeAdded)
    .HasColumnType("datetime2");
```

This creates a `datetime2(7)` column in the database. If you want to finetune the precision you can use:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
    .Property(f => f.DateTimeAdded)
    .HasColumnType("datetime2")
    .HasPrecision(0);
```

... for a `datetime2(0)` column in the DB.

However, the code you have shown in your question works because the `datetime` type allows to store dates back to around 1750. The exception occurs only for earlier dates. A common reason for this exception is an uninitialized `DateTime` property because it represents the year 0001 which can't be stored in a `datetime` column in SQL Server.

There is no corresponding attribute to define this with data annotations. It's only possible with Fluent API.

Comment: Is not the `DateAdded` property properly initialized in my code example?

Comment: @Paperjam: It is, but is this *exactly* the code you have tested or is there perhaps another `DateTime` property in your test model which is not initialized? If not, then it's a weird thing. I'm using `datetime` columns quite often and `DateTime` properties are never a problem when initialized with `Now`. I had tested your example yesterday to convince myself again, and it didn't throw an exception.

Comment: Doh! Yeah, I've got an uninitialized property. I think I'll start on my repository pattern model so as to avoid silly mistakes like this. Thank you for your help! I'm going to definitely check out more of the Fluent API.

Comment: Be careful about the EF version 4.3.1 adds some fixes. See this post for details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466677/entity-framework-4-3-code-first-cannot-create-datetime2

Comment: The annotations do work ! No need to use the modelbuilder

Answer (score 32):

When saving a date it needs to have a value populated. Thats why you get this error.

Just use `DateTime?`. There is no need for the magic above.

Comment: In my sample code, when I initialize a new `Book` class, I am setting `DateAdded` to `DateTime.Now`. Is not the value effectively populated, or am I missing something?

Comment: On second thought, it is. As I recall the problem I was having was with my repository code where the `DateAdded` was not, in fact, being set. And using a nullable field, while useful for preventing oversights from mine from firing off errors, would have not met the requirements of my application. +1 for a good suggestion though.

Comment: Use a nullable type if that's what you want in your model, but if you don't, you shouldn't use it just so your seed or other initializer works.

Comment: If i don't want to make it the nullable than i mean requirement of the project to not consider this field nullable.

Answer (score 31):

You can annotate the attribute of your class with the type datetime2.

```
public class Book
{
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: smalldatetime can also be used

Answer (score 2):

If migrations are enabled you can also adjust stuff right there.

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.MyTable",
        c => new
        {
            Date = c.DateTime(false, 7, storeType: "datetime2"),
        });
}
```