# How to work around EF 4.1, CodeFirst C# DateTime datetime2 vs. datetime incompatibility

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4.1, code-first, datetime2

My Code First models have `System.DateTime` properties. When the database seeding code is invoked, it throws this exception:

> SqlException (0x80131904): The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I am creating a new `DateTime` object with the constructor. Code First is creating the database schema. How do I overcome this apparent bug in Code First? I am not particular about my datatype. I merely need to store a date, and optionally a time of day, but not crucial.

I have searched and read a lot of posts, but none with this error specify they come from CodeFirst-generated data scheme. The closest answer I found involved making a change to the `ProviderManifestToken` in the `edmx` file, but my project does not have an `edmx` file. I did not use the designer, I am using Code First.

Answer (score 3):

EF maps `DateTime` in .NET to `datetime` in SQL Server. The types have a different range: `datetime` can store only dates later than around the year 1750. If you try to store a `DateTime` in your entity with an earlier date or an unitialized `DateTime` (which has year 1) you get the exception because SQL Server cannot store this.

Solution:

- Either make sure that the dates you want to store are later than 1750
- Or map you `DateTime` properties explitely to `datetime2` in SQL Server which has a wider range. Example how to define this mapping with Fluent API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8044310/270591

Actually I also had expected a default mapping to `datetime2` because it fits better to `DateTime` in .NET. But for some reason they decided to use `datetime` as default.

Comment: Thanks please see my own answer for an explanation.

Comment: @billy: You can use annotations to define the `datetime2` type: `[Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]`. There is no attribute to define the precision explicitly. But you could try (example for precision 0): `[Column(TypeName = "datetime2(0)")]`. I am not sure if that will work though.

Comment: @billy: The second annotation with `[Column(TypeName = "datetime2(0)")]` doesn't seem to work. I just tested it and I get an exception. It looks that the precision can only be defined with Fluent API.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found out after more careful debugging that the error was coming from a data entity initialization that involved me not specifying any value for the `DateTime`.

I had thought it was coming from a long data seeding statement that involved new `DateTime(2012, 2, 19, 19, 0, 0)` or some such. Thanks to Slauma for his efforts - he was correct that it was due to unitialized values.