# If I use nullable(of DateTime) does that solve my DateTime2 issues in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

Using Code First technique with EF6

When I declare my DateTime properties like this:

```
Public Property StartDate As DateTime
```

I get this error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The statement has been terminated.
```

When I change my declaration to this:

```
Public Property StartDate As Nullable(Of DateTime)
```

Everything is fine.

What I don't understand is why. I have seen in other SO posts that we need to use DateTime2 with SQL, but I don't know what that means.  It's not a type in code.  Is it something else I should be setting up?

Am I taking a shortcut using the `nullable` declaration or is that automatically changing to `datetime2` during the EF processes?

Comment: Nullable type just remedy the problem when `DateTime` property has not been set (it defaults to null instead of `DateTime.MinValue` which the problem originates), if you really want to use non-nullable `DateTime` property in Code First then you can configure `HasColumnType("datetime2")` explicitly with `DbModelBuilder`. Note that EF handles `DateTime` .NET properties as `datetime2` data type by default.

Comment: Thx for explaining why my problem was solved w/o any other actions.  Regarding DbModelBuilder, I'm not familiar with that and the links I found don't explain it to me.  Do you have some favorite links with examples?  It also seems like you're saying EF `is` already using datetime2 and I don't need to take anymore action, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: The `DateTime` structure in .NET is equivalent to `datetime2` in SQL Server (using same minimum value, i.e. `0001-01-01 00:00:00`). On the other hand, `datetime` in SQL Server uses different minimum value, hence 'out-of-range' value occurs when non-nullable `DateTime` with its default value inserted to `datetime` column (nullable `DateTime` can be mapped to `NULL`, which is default value to nullable column in SQL).

Comment: @Alan: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043816/using-datetime-properties-in-code-first-entity-framework-and-sql-server/8044310#8044310 and/or https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/229/conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out-of-range-value

Comment: @cloudikka So if we use the `Nullable` option, is it the case that SQL Server allows a null date, but if there's a date, it just has to be greater than Jan 1st 1753?  So there's `gap` of storable values when not using datetime2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create custom EF convention and plug it to instruct Entity Framework how to deal with every single property of DateTime.

Create following convention class.

```
public class DateTime2Convention : Convention
{
    public DateTime2Convention()
    {
        this.Properties<DateTime>()
            .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));        
    }
}
```

Then add custom convention to convention collection overriding OnModelBuilder method in class inheriting DbContext.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // existing code, if any

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new DateTime2Convention());
}
```

You might want to take a look at [Entity Framework Custom Code First Conventions (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819164(v=vs.113).aspx) for more info.

Comment: Didn't understand the 1st comment above.  But I believe this is my answer.  For the current project I will continue with the `Nullable` option, but appreciate the pointer (and links in your comment above) for how to change the convention so SQL automatically uses datetime2.  I don't understand why this was down voted.  Your answer seems right on target and there isn't a comment here to explain the down vote.

Comment: Down vote was correct. I edited my answer and replied to the comment. That was the comment you don't understand to. Happy coding!